# if S is c'pt set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then Pol(S) is dense subset of C(S)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

[image]

In book "Functional analysis" written by Lax, The Stone-Weierstrass theorem is stated in the same way as above. I wonder we can apply above theorem to prove that $S$ is compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then Pol(S) is dense subset of C(S). My confusion is due to my lack of accurate understanding of (iii).

I do not know the correct interpretation of the two interpretations for (iii).
First interpretation of (iii) is "For any distinct $p$ and $q$, there exist f in E s.t $f(p)\neq f(q)$.
and second interpretation of (iii) is "there exist a f in E such that for all distinct $p$ and $q$, $f(p)\neq f(q)$ "

if first interpretation is correct we can use Pol(S) as E. because for $p=(p_1,p_2), q=(q_1,q_2)\in S$ we can use $f_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ if $p_1\neq q_1$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ if $p_2\neq q_2$.

However if 2nd interpretation is correct, I don't know there exist polynomial which satisfy (iii).

What is the correct interpretation for (iii) in the Stone-Weierstrauss theorem?

Comment: First interpretation.   Before attempting to apply the S-W theorem, perhaps it would be good to understand a proof of the S-W theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!